# Flutter (dart) file upload, progress bar - file upload stream not give back data during upload

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, multipartform-data

At file upload to server, I would like to display the upload status.
At ios, I don't have information from the stream. My code(part):

```
var multipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromPath("video", file);
request.files.add(multipartFile);
request.fields.addAll(queryParameterss);

print('1');

_response = await request.send();

print('2');

_response.stream.listen((value) {
  print(value.last);
});

if(_response.statusCode==200){
  print("Video uploaded");
}else{
  print("Video upload failed");
}
```

The console prints:

flutter: 1

flutter: 2

flutter: Video uploaded

flutter: 49 - this come from stream

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could tackle the issue like this:

```
final stream = await request.send();

print(stream.statusCode);

final response = await http.Response.fromStream(stream);
```

then you could parse the response like below:

```
final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);

print("response is : $jsonResponse");
```

or you can straight away assign it to your `_response` variable if it's an instance of `Future<Response>` like this:

```
_response = await http.Response.fromStream(stream);
```

Note that I have an import like this:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Comment: Same result. At the end of the progress, it shows only the status, and the data provided by the server.. But during the upload, there is no data...